# How to select the second to last character in block mode vim

Tags: vim

How do I select the second to last character in block mode such that I can run the [Visual Incrementing script](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#VISINCR) on it

```
private static final int averagePace=1;   
private static final int altitudeGained=1;   
private static final int averageHeartate=1;
```

Edit:
What I want to get to:

```
private static final int averagePace=1;   
private static final int altitudeGained=2;   
private static final int averageHeartate=3;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't visually select data from different columns on multiple lines. You can use `<C-v>` and motion commands to visually select a block of text based on columns, but you can't select different columns on each line, and it looks like that's what your plugin requires to operate.

If you're merely trying to increment the `1` to `2` over a range of lines, Vim has a simple built-in way to do that in this case: visually select all three lines, and then press `<C-a>`. It will increment the first number on each line.

Comment: I want to have 1 2 3 .... at the end of the line. Is there any quick way to do that?

Comment: Now that you've added sample output to your question, this solution doesn't apply. I assume your plugin does that? You could pre-align the numbers in order to visually select, by using a plugin like [Tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) or [Align](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Align), but that's a bit of a hack, and then you'd need a macro to un-align if you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

this will work... we can use the pattern match

```
:let i=1 | <range>g/=\zs1\ze;/ s//\=i/ | let i=i+1
```

here `<range>` is something like `10,25` start line and end line